# Inner padding (ipadx, ipady) only works on right side and bottom of frame

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, border, padding

There seems to be an issue with the `ipadx` and `ipady` adjustments of the `grid` method. I tried to add inner padding around a frame such that the elements/subframes contained get "pushed" away from the border resulting in symmetrical whitespace:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font


# Main window
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title('Viewer')

# Main window plotting frame
main_window_plotting_frame = tk.Frame(main_window, borderwidth=2, relief='raised')
main_window_plotting_frame.grid(sticky='nesw')

# General layout settings
default_font = tk.font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
default_font.configure(size=11)
title_font = ('TkDefaultFont', 12, 'bold')
small_padding = 5
large_padding = 20

# Preview image frame
preview_frame = tk.Frame(main_window_plotting_frame)
preview_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=100, ipady=100)

preview_frame_title = tk.Label(preview_frame, text='Preview', font=title_font)
preview_frame_title.grid(row=0, pady=large_padding)

preview_canvas = tk.Canvas(preview_frame, width=300, height=300, bg='white')
preview_canvas.grid(row=1)
preview_canvas.create_line(0, 300, 300, 0, width=10, fill='light green')

preview_save_button = tk.Button(preview_frame, text='Save as PNG')
preview_save_button.grid(row=2)

# Open main window
main_window.mainloop()
```

But this results in padding only to the right and the bottom. I've searched for an explanation and only found another user with the same issue, but no solution. I've exaggerated the `ipadx` and `ipady` values to make the effect more prominent.

The reason I want inner padding is that I'm trying to solve the annoying issue of "accumulating" whitespace/borders/paddings in complex GUIs with multiple nested frames/subframes. I found that in order to avoid accumulation of padding, one can just eliminate **all** padding altogether - *except* for the innermost subframes containing the actual GUI widgets. By doing this, I can use frames in order to group widgets and move them around like modular instrumentation panels, while keeping a constant padding around each such panel. This grouping is not just convenient, but a necessity as it becomes mind-numbingly tedious to edit/maintain complex GUIs without proper grouping into frames and subframes.

*UPDATE*: An explanation, why the suggested solution of adding another subframe with the same problem doesn't work:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font


# Main window
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title('Viewer')

# Main window plotting frame
main_window_plotting_frame = tk.Frame(main_window, borderwidth=2, relief='raised')
main_window_plotting_frame.grid(sticky='nesw')

# General layout settings
default_font = tk.font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
default_font.configure(size=11)
title_font = ('TkDefaultFont', 12, 'bold')
small_padding = 5
large_padding = 20

# Preview image frame
preview_frame = tk.Frame(main_window_plotting_frame)
preview_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=100, ipady=100)

preview_preview_frame = tk.Frame(main_window_plotting_frame)
preview_preview_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=100, ipady=100)

preview_frame_title = tk.Label(preview_frame, text='Preview', font=title_font)
preview_frame_title.grid(row=0, pady=large_padding)

preview_canvas = tk.Canvas(preview_frame, width=300, height=300, bg='white')
preview_canvas.grid(row=1)
preview_canvas.create_line(0, 300, 300, 0, width=10, fill='light green')

preview_canvas = tk.Canvas(preview_preview_frame, width=300, height=300, bg='white')
preview_canvas.grid(row=1)
preview_canvas.create_line(0, 300, 300, 0, width=10, fill='light green')

preview_save_button = tk.Button(preview_frame, text='Save as PNG')
preview_save_button.grid(row=2)

# Open main window
main_window.mainloop()
```

By adding a `canvas` also to the second subframe, you'll see that the problem persists (only now you have asymmetric padding in two instead of one frame).

Comment: Use `padx` instead of `ipadx`. `ipadx` pads internally. I guess that means, that if you only have one widget inside a frame, there is nothing it can pad it to. Because if you add a second frame into `main_window_plotting_frame`, you can `ipad` them in respect to each other. I hope this made sense with all this padding ;D

Comment: I'm actually trying to find a workaround to avoid `padx`/`pady` and use internal padding instead, because I want to simplify a complex GUI with multiple nested frames, subframes, and widgets. Since I don't want to define custom paddings for each widget/element, I found that using zero padding for **all** frames/subframes except the innermost one would solve the issue. And here, I'd like to use inner padding so there is no additional padding between adjacent subframes that would lead to additional, unwanted whitespace

Comment: Try drawing a GUI with nested subframes and you'll immediately see the problem of "accumulating" whitespaces between nested elements...and how this can be solved by eliminating **all** padding except for the innermost widgets/subframes. By doing this, I can use frames for grouping elements without adding unwanted whitespace, while the right amount of whitespace is added by the elements (the innermost subframes) themselves so they get some padding and don't overlap

Comment: So I want to use frames only to be able to shift around elements in groups ("panels"), that's the idea

Comment: I've updated the question to include the motivation behind

Comment: I gave an answer, where I changed a little of your code. I hope I got it right what you mean, but I think it is really an issue of having just one widget in a frame.